# A Ranger build that is close to Tier 3 classes

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, ranger

As the title suggests, I am looking for a Ranger dual wielder build that can compete with Tier 3 classes.

Our party is quite imbalanced as it is composed of a Druid, a Wizard, a Dread Necro, a Swordsage (new addition) and a Ranger. The casters are inexperienced players so they do not powerplay much, but the Dread Necro and the Swordsage (me) have some experience, and will probably dominate the game. My Swordsage has not been played yet, but he is roughly optimised.

So, to even things out, I am looking for a dual wielding build strong enough to be considered Tier 3. I would prefer Ranger as the main class and maybe a prestige class or two, but not builds with 4-5 classes, prestige or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the builds [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19872930/The_3.5_Ranger_Handbook). Note that dual-wielding is considered the hardest of the ranger builds to optimize due to the resource requirements.

Ranger 6/Swordsage 14 looks to be an excellent bet save for the presence of an SS in your party. However, given that this is a dex-wis swordsage, it should work well in synergy, rather than fighting for the same theme.

[This](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=4621.msg153803#msg153803):

> Cloistered cleric1/wildshape ranger17/monk2 (not necessarily in that order
>
> Class variants:
>
> Trades knowledge domain for knowledge devotion feat (CC)
>
> Trades one of his evasions for spell reflection (CM)
>
> Key feats: able learner, natural spell, sword of the arcane order, ascetic hunter, mulitattack, improved natural attack (unarmed strikes), practiced spellcaster, potentially a metamagic feat and DMM
>
> 18 BAB, unarmed strike damage as a 19th level monk

This seems quite solid to me. You've got a bit of castery, some nice wildshaping for utility, and significant damage. That should get you to tier 3 without too much trouble.

Huuuge list of builds [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19861694/The_3.5_Ranger_Thread_%282nd_posting%29). But my recommendation would be to refluff something else into ranger. Or borrow from pathfinder updates and just shove them back into the old class to boost its... utility.

Comment: Yeah, even in my pathfinder game the two dual wielders are feeling the bite of buying two expensive weapons.  The cost impediment is the worst, except perhaps for caster/melee types.

Comment: ECL 7 (IL 4) is a weird choice for starting an initiating career. I'd try to hop into, say, Barbarian and/or Cleric to start at 9th (IL 5).

Comment: Your list of builds is a dead link (WotC boards are kaput)

Answer (score 21):

### Ranger 20

No, stop, don't leave! Hear me out. On its own, the ranger is actually a *really good class* when all options are in play. This answer used to make this argument in a slightly different (and technically-incorrect) way, but I've come back to this seven years later to update it. [I've also wrote an extremely in-depth handbook on the matter (rangers in 3.5)](https://hexdrake.support/ranger_handbook/) if you want a more comprehensive read.

Anyway, ranger is really strong. When all options are available, I would go as far as calling it "the platonic ideal of tier 3," as it brings a number of very powerful and versatile options to the table.

#### The ingredients:

In an "all sources open" context (important since most of the best ranger options are from *Dragon Magazine*), the ranger's main ingredients are the following:

1. The base chassis. Ranger sports 6+Int mod skills, a d8 Hit Die, full BAB, two good saves, and martial weapon proficiencies. As classes go, it's hard to get better on a raw stat level.
2. The **solitary hunting** ACF (Dr347 p. 91), which trades your animal companion for the ability to add your favored enemy bonus on attack rolls. Alternatively, the Tactical Advantage feat (Dr335 p. 91) does the same thing, but for only one of your favored enemies (they don't stack). This is *huge*, catapulting your attack bonus beyond what normal martials can get (useful for TWF and Power Attack especially).
3. ***Enemy spirit pouches*** (MIC p. 97). These 2,100gp items from the *Magic Item Compendium* either give you a new favored enemy (keyed to the item) or up your current Favored Enemy bonus by +2 (if you already have that item). Wearing one of your own type hurts, so don't do that. Do get as many of these as you can though, and swap them out as needed before fights. If you can    use the item combining rules to duct tape multiples together, do that as well.
4. **Favored Power Attack** (CWar p. 98). This is a feat that requires BAB +4 and Power Attack, and boosts your Power Attack multiplier to ×3 for two-handing or ×2 for one-handing. This has an odd side effect of making rangers want to fight with a pair of one-handed weapons (or a two-hander and unarmed strikes) instead of light weapons like most TWFers.

Of course, that isn't going to be super useful if your favored enemy isn't in front of you, so let's talk about favored enemies:

#### Broad Favored Enemies

In addition to Favored Power Attack and *enemy spirit pouches*, some notable options for this are the following. Note that you only use the highest applicable bonus against a favored enemy; you don't stack the buff against creatures that fit multiple categories.

- **Favored enemy (evil creatures)** via the Uthgardt Barbarian origin (FRCS p.168), allowing you to apply your favored enemy bonus against
  any evil creature you fight.
- **Favored enemy (arcanists)** via the arcane hunter ACF (CMag p. 32), allowing you to apply your favored enemy bonus against arcane
  spellcasters and invocation users, the first of which is an extremely
  common "powerful enemy" to face.
- Various **urban ranger** ACFs (Dr310
  p. p. 59, MotW p. 15, [SRD](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#rangerVariantUrbanRanger) will let you choose an organization
  (with incredibly broad examples, like "that nation's army") as a
  favored enemy, getting your bonuses against anyone from that
  organization.

Note that, with Favored Power Attack, you only need a lowest-bonus favored enemy to get the massive triple damage boost, so even just stacking *enemy spirit pouches* will let you excel in damage.

There are three more things to recommend that I think deserve their own sections:

#### Combat Styles

The ranger has a plethora of combat styles to choose from, but in your case, there are two important ones to decide between:

1. **(a)** Two-Weapon Fighting: the one from the *Player's Handbook*. Two-Weapon Fighting, Improved Two-Weapon Fighting, Greater Two-Weapon Fighting. This is, ironically, the one you take if you're not building like a normal TWFer. If you don't expect to have the Dexterity score to meet the prerequisites normally, go for this.
2. **(b)** Strong Arm Style (Dr326, p. 97): Power Attack, Improved Sunder, Great Cleave. We only care about the first one. You *really* want Favored Power Attack. If you don't expect to ever have Str 13+, then this is a good choice of combat styles.

#### Spellcasting

Ranger spells are actually really good. There are too many to go over here, but notable examples include *entangle* and *impeding stones*, *plant growth*, various weapon boosts, and *lion's charge* to give you pounce at later levels. Rangers make excellent use of wands as well. For a summary of how ranger spellcasting works and what's especially amazing on the list, [follow this link](https://hexdrake.support/ranger_handbook/#c4-spell-short).

In addition, you have access to the Sword of the Arcane Order feat, which can get you access to wizard spells! I've got a full writeup of how that works at [this link](https://hexdrake.support/ranger_handbook/#c6-sotaa). The feat is *very* good, but also requires a lot more bookkeeping (heh, literally even), so keep that in mind.

#### Being a Good Guy and Exalted Feats

Exalted-good rangers have access to the incredible Nemesis feat from the *Book of Exalted Deeds*. This feat gives you the best sensory ability in the game: the ability to unconditionally pinpoint any creature of the chosen favored enemy type within 60 feet. Walls and other barriers explicitly do *not* block this sense, and it means you're never going to be snuck up on by one of your Favored Enemy selections. You also deal +1d6 damage on any attack against evil examples of the favored enemy you choose, but that's less important. You can take this feat multiple times, and might *want* to, it's just that good.

In addition, if your DM doesn't let you have the Uthgardt Barbarian origin enemy from the *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting*, there are two prestige classes that give a variant favored enemy (evil), the Stalker of Kharash (BoED p. 75) and the Harper Paragon (PGtF p. 181). These have rough prerequisites but can give you access to that kind of wide-ranging favored enemy if you can't get it baseline. Harper Paragon is the better of the two, but is a little more annoying to enter.

#### Builds

A dip into either Spirit Lion Totem Barbarian (pounce) or Cloistered Cleric (Knowledge Devotion, Travel Devotion) is a very good choice. As a TWFer, you'll be full attacking in an ideal situation, and if you're full attacking, you need the ability to engage in combat.

My overall recommendation is a Strength-based Barbarian 1/Ranger X. Initiator dips after capping out your spells can also be quite good. Still, ranger 20 is perfectly valid and fairly strong.

If you want some longer and more detailed builds, I've made seven complete, 1-to-20 "plug and play" builds that have every choice needed already listed, including skills, feats, and gear. [You can find them at this link](https://hexdrake.support/example_builds/); some of them are ranger 20, some are ranger/scout Swift Hunter multiclasses, and some use prestige classes.

Comment: This might be the first time I've ever seen the Ranger optimized for the purpose of being a Ranger, very nicely.

Comment: Nice answer! But one thing: where is the matching note for the “\*” on the title?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie it was meant to go on the very last line, talking about Ranger 20. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Ah, that's a good point. I was mostly writing this from memory, and didn't actually crack my Player's Guide to Faerun to double-check as I should have. After checking the books, you are entirely correct about the rule that allows you to take *multiple* regional feats. I've edited my post.

Comment: Cool. I rescind my petty objection. That said, I think there's probably a place in all but the most feat-strapped straight-up ranger build to take the 11th-level moon-warded ranger substitution level (*Dragon* #340 55).  Such a ranger trades a bonus feat for immunity to *harmful* mind-affecting effects (e.g. immune to *suggestion* but can still benefit from *heroism*), which is pretty spiffy.

Comment: Yeah, I was considering mentioning that (the +Wis to AC at level 2 is pretty neat), but on a Mystic Ranger, it comes online a level later, and a TWFer is fest-starved enough that they probably do need their combat style as a combat style.

Comment: Regarding “a better ally of justice and scourge of evil than the paladin ever was,” paladin is actually an interesting option here: holy judge from *Champions of Valor* can get favored enemy (devils) instead of smite evil, and then *Unearthed Arcana* can give favored enemy (one of a few choices) instead of lay on hands. Combine that with Serenity and moon-warded ranger, and you’re looking at Wis to quite a lot of things, and starting a decent leg up on collecting favored enemies.

Comment: Why didn't I know about those pouches!!! Thanks for mentioning them!

Comment: Mystic Ranger doesn't get an animal companion to lose for Solitary Hunter...

Comment: I finally came back and edited this post to remove inaccuracies.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways that are commonly used to grant Rangers the flexibility associated with Tier 3 status. The first is the most well-known: The so-called [Wildshape Ranger](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#ranger) variant from Unearthed Arcana, but it is of limited usefulness to two-weapon fighting Rangers.

More appropriate to your situation is the other method: The combination of the *Mystic Ranger* variant from Dragon Magazine 336 and the *Sword of the Arcane Order* feat from Champions of Valor. The Mystic Ranger variant has the effect of significantly improving upon the Ranger's spellcasting progression, while the Sword of the Arcane Order feat allows the Ranger to prepare Wizard spells. The combined effect is a massive increase in flexibility and, once buff spells have been taken into account, combat ability.

Comment: Mystic SotAO seems... It's Tier 1 (spells comparable to a Wizard on a Ranger chassis) until level 10, and then it just... stops. It might drop down to, or even past, Tier 3 by the time you get to 20th level, but it definitely should be mentioned as a *very* strange case that does not fit nicely into the typical tier system.